# Understanding the execution

Tags: architecture

Whats the execution flow when Salesforce record is inserted and by the way I am not looking for SF documentation but logical explanation of why something is executed in the order mentioned in sf documentation i.e. why can't we have workflow rules  and field updates before the after trigger that way no need to execute them again if it entails field update. Please assist.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR version:**

Salesforce has put a lot of thought into when things are executed.
Without input from an authoritative source inside of Salesforce, the best we can do is guess. This is one of those things that can't really be changed after it's been set (because any re-arrangement of existing items is very likely to break things for many customers).

**Long version:**

What follows is largely speculation, and my best guess at why the Order of Execution (OoE) is the way it is.

When a record is saved (inserted, updated, deleted, or undeleted), there are a number of things that need to happen. Validation rules, triggers, workflow, assignment rules, etc... These can't all be done at the same time, so **we need to decide which order to execute them in**.

**The order** that we execute those things in **needs to be consistent**, or else the same Salesforce customizations (Apex classes, triggers, workflow, etc...), with the exact same input, may produce different results.

To avoid unpredictable behavior, and to make it easier to order the tasks that need to be executed (or easier for people to agree on the order), there should be some rules.

## What rules might govern the order of execution?

Some things are pretty obvious, and come from how databases (in general) do things. `after` triggers should not run before we run the `before` triggers. Records should not be saved before we have a chance to modify them some more (the entire point of before triggers is to modify a record without requiring DML).

While the general Salesforce motto is "Clicks, not code", I think that motto is reversed when it comes time to execute things. **Code before clicks**, or **Clicks after code**. As a corollary, it seems that **things which are less configurable are run first**.

Another principle that Salesforce seems to follow in execution is **breadth before depth** or **finish what you started before moving on**. Put another way, Salesforce wants to finish up doing the immediate work on the initiating object (breadth) before starting to do work on other objects (hierarchical depth). This may be an arbitrary decision, but I have a feeling that doing things this way is more stable than the alternative.

## Trying to apply these rules to the OoE

1. System validation rules (if the change comes from the UI).

   - overruling UI input because of code would probably confuse the user, best to let them know about their errors before we try to mess with data in code
2. User-defined validation rules are sometimes run next (Opp Line Items and Quote Line Items)

   - More declarative than system validation rules
3. Before triggers are run

   - Code before clicks
4. System validation and User-defined validation rules are run

   - Finish up working on initiating object
   - Clicks after code
   - (Eric) Applies validation to the potential changes from the before triggers
5. Duplicate Rules

   - Finish up working on initiating object (breadth)
   - Clicks after code
   - More declarative than validation?
   - (Eric) Allows for custom duplicate detection from trigger to happen first giving control to the developer to meet their requirements
6. Records Saved, but not committed

   - Standard database behavior
7. After triggers are run

   - Standard database behavior, running the `after` events after data is saved
   - Code before clicks
   - Trigger context variables are read-only, too late to try to change data to comply with Validation rules
   - Usually runs DML on other objects (depth)
8. Assignment rules

   - Clicks after code
   - Works on initiating object (breadth)
   - (Eric) Since the record can no longer be modified the assignment rules have concrete criteria to work with
9. Auto-response rules

   - Clicks after code
   - More declarative than Assignment rules, has some 'depth' (sending emails)
   - (Eric) Since the record can no longer be modified the Auto-Response rules have concrete criteria to work with. This and assignment rules should be based on the data coming in and not data modified by workflow rule coming below as workflow was not thought of as changing data that would affect these rule. They are workflow after all.
10. Workflow is run

    - Clicks after code
    - Very declarative
    - Field updates can be cross-object, so treat it like it's 'depth' instead of 'breadth'
    - (Eric) Once we get here all of our custom code, processes, etc have happened so the workflow can take the final record and do what it needs
11. Run before/after triggers one final time (+ standard validation rules) if there was a workflow field update on the current object

    - Code before clicks
    - Gives us a chance to react to field updates on the initiating object while giving some assurance that we won't loop infinitely
12. Other declarative stuff
13. Rollups calculated on parents, parents undergo save operation

    - Clicks after code
    - Doesn't make much sense to run this if there's a chance that the child record could still change
14. Rollups calculated on grandparents, grandparents undergo save operation

    - Clicks after code
    - More depth than rollups on Parent records
    - Doesn't make much sense to run this if there's a chance that the child record could still change

## So, why not run workflow before the `after` triggers?

We can't guarantee that workflow won't contain cross-object work to be done. If 'breadth before depth' is one of the rules, this would run the risk of breaking the rule.

Breaking up workflow into this-object and cross-object would take resources to compute, and require two different executions of workflow. This is less than ideal, would make the OoE even more complex.

Having some workflow cause triggers to be executed again, and others not, is not consistent (and why would a change to a field on another object not cause that object's triggers to run? That would be some very exceptional behavior). It would be a cause for confusion.

The best way to avoid confusion is to have clear rules, and to **adhere to them consistently**.

Comment: Rather than writing a new answer, yours is well thought out, I added a few of my comments to your (Eric). Feel free to modify or remove them.....